# Creating a custom class and using it in ASPX code behind file

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I've downloaded a sample `website` application from internet that is built using legacy ASP.NET 2.0 WebForms. This application has a custom class named clsTest. In a code behind page Test.aspx.cs this class is declared as:

```
public clsTest myTest;
```

But when I compile app I get the following error on the above declaration: `The type or namespace name 'clsTest' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

**Snapshot of code behind page Test.aspx.cs**:

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI;
using myNameSpace;

namespace myNameSpace
{
    public partial class Test : Page
    {
        public int TotalMethods;

        public bool bVal;

        public clsTest myTest;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          ....
        }
      ....
      ....
    }
}
```

**Question**: Even if I declare `using myNameSpace;` on top of the code behind page where the `clsTest` is declared, I'm still getting the above error. Why? Following is a snapshot of the clsTest class:

```
namespace myNameSpace
{
    public class clsTest
    {
        public bool Errors;

        public string FirstName;
        public bool FirstNameErr;

        public string LastName;
        public bool LastNameErr;
     }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Following is a screen capture of the actual legacy ASP.NET website project that I downloaded from the internet. In this actual app, the class in question is `CCProcessor`. As you can see in the screenshot below, `CCProcessor.cs` file is in the root folder of the project and I'm declaring the `using ...` statement at the top, yet the tooltip in the screenshot is still complaining about missing directive or an assembly. Why? Same error for another class `PaymentSettings` that is also present in the root folder of the project. **NOTE**: To see the picture clearly you may want to click on it to see in the entire browser.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried putting the class definition in the same .cs files as the Test class?

Comment: You have named your class as cslTest but referencing it as clsTest

Comment: @CodingDawg I've corrected the typo. But the problem persists.

Comment: @nam Did my answer fix your problem?

Comment: @CodingDawg Do you happen to know how to find out if the `clsTest` is in a different assembly or project? This probably is the case but I can't find out the assembly the class would be in? Since it's a legacy ASP.NET **website** project it does not have Reference folder either where I could have searched the assembly. And there is no other project inside the Visual Studio Solution.

Comment: @nam Can you post a screen shot of your solution explorer.

Comment: @CodingDawg Sure, I'll do it today. I don't have access to it right now.

Comment: @CodingDawg Per your request, I've added a screenshot of the actual project in a new UPDATE section of my post above.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be having the clsTest class in a different project or assembly and might not be referencing correctly in your web project.

Try to have the clsTest class in the same file and it should work.

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI;
using myNameSpace;

namespace myNameSpace
{
    public partial class Test : Page
    {
          public int TotalMethods;

          public bool bVal;

         public clsTest myTest;

          protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
            ....
         }
       ....
      ....
    }

    public class clsTest
    {
        public bool Errors;

        public string FirstName;
        public bool FirstNameErr;

        public string LastName;
        public bool LastNameErr;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the class .cs file in the App_Code folder.